# Hide everything inside a div except a single element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Let's say I got the following structure:

```
<div id="le-main-id" class="le-main-class">
  <div id="le-main-id1" class="le-main-class1"></div>
  <div id="le-main-id2" class="le-main-class2"></div>
  <div id="le-main-id3" class="le-main-class3"></div>
</div>
```

And I need to hide everything, except the div number 2 ( id="le-main-id2" class="le-main-class2"), but I can't just go on each element and use `display:none` because in my real code I got like 40 divs to hide, so it might take too long and ending up in a mess.

so how can I hide everything except the second div?

Something like this

```css
#le-main-id.le-main-class2 { /* visible:yes; all the others: no; */}
#le-main-id { /* visible:no; */}
```

UPDATE:
I followed the answers, but it's not working. This is how I'm trying:

```
#lehometemplates > :not (.wpbdp-field-title) {
display: none !important;
}
```

UPDATE 2: 
I believe I didn't formulate the question 100%, even though the current answers are indeed helpful. Let me make it more clear:

Suppose that's what I have:

```
<div id="le-main-id" class="le-main-class">
 <div id="1" class="1">
  <div id="2" class="2"> 
   <div id="3" class="3"> 
    <div id="4" class="4">

          <div id="le-main-id1" class="le-main-class1">
            <div id="le-main-id1" class="le-main-class1"></div>
            <div id="le-main-id2" class="le-main-class2"></div>
            <div id="le-main-id3" class="le-main-class3"></div>
          </div>

    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

So to hide everything and keep the div `class="le-main-class2"` I'm going to use something like...

```
#le-main-id > :not (.le-main-class2)  {
    display: none !important;
    }
```

Is it right?

Look, I just don't want to have to select every parent div first, if that's possible.

**LAST UPDATE**

Finally made it, If I have the following code:

```
<div id="le-main-id" class="le-main-class">
 <div id="1" class="1">
  <div id="2" class="2"> 
   <div id="3" class="3"> 
    <div id="4" class="4">

          <div id="le-main-id111" class="le-main-class111">
            <div id="le-main-id1" class="le-main-class1"></div>
            <div id="le-main-id2" class="le-main-class2"></div>
            <div id="le-main-id3" class="le-main-class3"></div>
          </div>

    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Then all I should do is:

```
.le-main-class .le-main-class111 > :not(.le-main-class2) {
  display: none;
}
```

This way I'll hide every child of `.le-main-class` and `.le-main-class111`, except `.le-main-class2`.

Comment: Are your divs inside a parent container? (not the `<body>`)

Comment: Inside `id="le-main-id" class="le-main-class"`.

Comment: The updated selector doesn't match the posted HTML. Please add the relevant HTML as well.

Comment: Too many elements to update, I tried to make it the simplest possible.

Comment: @user3692451 When it comes to CSS selectors, the answer is highly dependent on the actual markup. Please provide the actual code and/or an online example on jsfiddle/jsbin/...

Comment: Note that `>` is child combinator which separates two selectors and matches the elements matched by the second selector that are direct descendants of elements matched by the first selector. If `.wpbdp-field-title` is not a child (or direct descendant) but a descendant of `#lehometemplates`, Then you should replace the `>` with a white space within the selector — that is called descendant combinator.

Comment: @user3692451 Just updated the answer according to the new markup.

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo-class:

```css
#le-main-id > :not(.le-main-class2) { display: none; }
```

It's worth noting that `:not()` [is supported in IE9+](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3).

---

For legacy web browsers, you could hide all the children `<div>`s and then override the declaration for a specific one.

```css
#le-main-id > div { display: none; }
#le-main-id > .le-main-class2 { display: block; }
```

---

### Update

According to the [new update](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29727122/5), the actual markup is more complicated than the one was posted before.

As nested elements *may* have other contents, One proper way to hide everything inside `#le-main-id` excluding `.le-main-class2` is to add [`visibility: hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) to the main container and re-set it back to `visible` on the `.le-main-class2`.

However, [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) leaves the occupied space. But we can fix that by adding `line-height: 0` to the main container and re-setting the value to `1.2` on the `.le-main-class2`.

**[Online Example](http://jsbin.com/sudabo/2/edit?html,css,output)**.

```css
* { margin: 0; /* just for demo */ }

#le-main-id {
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  
  background-color: gold;
}

#le-main-id img {
  display: none; /* to hide the images */
}

#le-main-id .le-main-class2 {
  visibility: visible;
  line-height: 1.2;
  
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="le-main-id" class="le-main-class">
  .le-main-class
 <div id="1" class="1"> id="1" class="1"
  <div id="2" class="2"> id="2" class="2"
   <div id="3" class="3"> id="3" class="3"
    <div id="4" class="4"> id="4" class="4"
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="">

          <div id="le-main-id1" class="le-main-class1">
            .le-main-class1
            <div id="le-main-id1" class="le-main-class1">.le-main-class1</div>
            <div id="le-main-id2" class="le-main-class2">.le-main-class2</div>
            <div id="le-main-id3" class="le-main-class3">.le-main-class3</div>
          </div>

    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<p>
  The rest of the document....
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis soluta in vel libero dicta similique dolore modi quidem deserunt numquam neque, quo excepturi atque autem, aspernatur consequuntur mollitia, officia aut.
</p>
```

Comment: "It's worth noting that :not() is supported in IE9+." You're saying IE9 doesn't support it?

Comment: @user3692451 No, I'm saying it is supported in IE 9/10/11 but for IE 7/8 you probably need to go with the second method.

Comment: I often forget that CSS and CSS3 are different... oh well. :D

Comment: @user3692451: Not exactly different but sometimes when you don't tag CSS3 it is unclear as to whether you would be willing to have a CSS3 answer or not (alteast from my point of view). IE9 does support `:not` selector. [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3).

Comment: That's what I mean :D

Answer (score 1):

The CSS3 `:not` selector is exactly for this case:

```css
.p > div:not(#c2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="p">
  <div id="c1">1</div>
  <div id="c2">2</div>
  <div id="c3">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a javascript way to hide everything except an element with a given id, and it's contents. In order to do this it also can not hide the parent elements.

```js
function hideExcept(el, id) {
    console.log(el.nodeName);
    var isgood = Array.from(el.children).reduce((a,c)=>{
        if (c.id == id){ // note you may want to filter by class or something here
            return true
        }
        return a || hideExcept(c, id)

    }, false)

    if (!isgood) {
        el.style.display = 'none'
    }
    return isgood
}

hideExcept(document, 'anyID') // put the id of the element where 'anyID' is
```